# How can I synchronize data between a custom application and Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom application (ASP.NET 4.5 with MSSQL back-end) and I need to synchronize data from this application's database into Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and vice versa. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well at a high level this can be achieved with plugins, workflows and web services.

To send data into Crm you can use web service calls to create or update records, there are a couple of different ways to do this, I would suggest starting on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334357.aspx). So basically on some event on your web app, make a web service call to Crm.

To send data from Crm to your web app, I would suggest using a custom plugin or workflow activity to add data to your web app database (assuming there is no web service endpoint here). A plugin or workflow activity can be fired from a variety of events, e.g. some data changes, plugin fire, data added to database. You can read more about [plugins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328490.aspx) and [custom workflow activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309745.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is a service called [Scribe](http://scribesoft.com/), the service synchronizes data from different
database sources in 2 ways.

The alternative way is to use triggers, but the SDK says that it is highly recommended to
not use triggers along with CRM 2011. So, I advise you to try Scribe.